# Connecting find -print0 and xargs -0

Tags: bash, find, xargs

`find` parameter `-print0` and `xargs` parameter `-0` are expected to work together. `man` page of `find` says:

> -print0 ....  This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

Well, they work for me as long as `find` produces some output. How can I get it to work when find produces NO output?

```
find /dev /sys /usr -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 | wc -l    # 3 - OK
find /dev /sys -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 | wc -l         # 2 - OK
find /dev -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 | wc -l              # 1 - OK
find /dev -maxdepth 0 -name "x" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 | wc -l    # 1 instead of 0 - Fail
```

Some bad things may happen, for example,

```
find -type d -name ... -print0 | xargs -0 du -sh
```

when no directories are found `xargs` invokes `du` without arguments and `du` assumes `.`

P.S. I know about `-exec` parameter of `find`, I just want to connect `find` and `xargs` properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU `xargs` features the following option:

> ```
>   --no-run-if-empty
>    -r
> ```
>
> If  the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.